# How get video files list on WinPhone?

Tags: c#, video, windows-phone-8

I want get video files list from Video in Collection (I suggest from Audio+Video Hub).
I tryed to use MediaLibrary (Microsoft.Xna), but I can see audio albums and songs, not video.

Could you please help me.

Thank you!

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15860293/does-wp8-support-to-read-video-from-media-library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, as for now, it is not possible to access videos from Media Library.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402541%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_Medialibrary) the supported operations.

Comment: thanks for your answer! And it is mean that we don't have solution for get video files from Hub?

Comment: Unfortunately yes. That's the reason, for example, why some messaging apps (e.g. Whatsapp) don't allow to attach videos from library, although they allow to send videos recorded from the app.

Answer (score 0):

Try SmoothStreamingMediaElement for audio and video hope it will help you

**XAML**

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.90*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.10*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <SSME:SmoothStreamingMediaElement x:Name="video" Grid.Row="0" />
        <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1">

            <Button   x:Name="PlayButton" Width="150" Click="PlayButton_Click"  Loaded="PlayButton_Loaded"/>
            <Button   x:Name="StopButton" Content="Stop" Width="100" Click="StopButton_Click" />

            <TextBlock x:Name="status"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="currentBitrate"/>

        </StackPanel>

        <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0"></Grid>
    </Grid>
```

**C# code:**

```
 public partial class VIdeoStraming : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        string VideoUrl,StreamingUrl;
        public VIdeoStraming()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
            VideoUrl = this.NavigationContext.QueryString["parameter0"];
            string Manifest="/Manifest";
            StreamingUrl = VideoUrl + Manifest;                     
        }

        private void PlayButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Monitor the state of the content to determine the right action to take on this button being clicked
            //and then change the text to reflect the next action
            switch (video.CurrentState)
            {
                case SmoothStreamingMediaElementState.Playing:
                    video.Pause();
                    PlayButton.Content = "Play";
                    break;
                case SmoothStreamingMediaElementState.Stopped:
                case SmoothStreamingMediaElementState.Paused:
                    video.Play();
                    PlayButton.Content = "Pause";
                    break;
            }
        }

        private void PlayButton_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (video.AutoPlay)
            {
                case false:
                    PlayButton.Content = "Play";
                    break;
                case true:
                    PlayButton.Content = "Pause";
                    break;
            }
        }

        private void StopButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            //This should simply stop the playback

                video.Stop();
                //We should also reflect the chang on the play button
                PlayButton.Content = "Play";

        }

        private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            video.CurrentStateChanged += new RoutedEventHandler(video_CurrentStateChanged);
            video.PlaybackTrackChanged += new EventHandler<Microsoft.Web.Media.SmoothStreaming.TrackChangedEventArgs>(video_PlaybackTrackChanged);
            //video.SmoothStreamingSource = new Uri("http://64.120.251.114:1945/live/sharedobjects/layoutvideo/mp4:1311370468970.MP4/Manifest");
            video.SmoothStreamingSource = new Uri(StreamingUrl);
            video.ManifestReady += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(video_ManifestReady);
        }

        //when use in mobile device
        void video_ManifestReady(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SmoothStreamingMediaElement ssme = sender as SmoothStreamingMediaElement;

            if (ssme == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            // Select the highest band of tracks which all have the same resolution.
            // maxMobileBitrate depends on the encoding settings
            const ulong maxMobileBitrate = 1000000;
            foreach (SegmentInfo segment in ssme.ManifestInfo.Segments)
            {
                foreach (StreamInfo streamInfo in segment.AvailableStreams)
                {
                    if (MediaStreamType.Video == streamInfo.Type)
                    {
                        List<TrackInfo> widestBand = new List<TrackInfo>();
                        List<TrackInfo> currentBand = new List<TrackInfo>();
                        ulong lastHeight = 0;
                        ulong lastWidth = 0;
                        ulong index = 0;

                        foreach (TrackInfo track in streamInfo.AvailableTracks)
                        {
                            index += 1;

                            string strMaxWidth;
                            string strMaxHeight;
                            // If can't find width/height, choose only the top bitrate.
                            ulong ulMaxWidth = index;
                            // If can't find width/height, choose only the top bitrate.
                            ulong ulMaxHeight = index;
                            // V2 manifests require "MaxWidth", while v1 manifests used "Width".
                            if (track.Attributes.TryGetValue("MaxWidth", out strMaxWidth) ||
                                track.Attributes.TryGetValue("Width", out strMaxWidth))
                            {
                                ulong.TryParse(strMaxWidth, out ulMaxWidth);
                            }

                            if (track.Attributes.TryGetValue("MaxHeight", out strMaxHeight) ||
                                track.Attributes.TryGetValue("Height", out strMaxHeight))
                            {
                                ulong.TryParse(strMaxHeight, out ulMaxHeight);
                            }

                            if (ulMaxWidth != lastWidth ||
                                ulMaxHeight != lastHeight)
                            {
                                // Current band is now finished, check if it is the widest.
                                // If same size, current band preferred over previous
                                // widest, because it will be of higher bitrate.
                                if (currentBand.Count >= widestBand.Count)
                                {
                                    //  A new widest band:
                                    widestBand = currentBand;
                                    currentBand = new List<TrackInfo>();
                                }
                            }

                            if (track.Bitrate > maxMobileBitrate)
                            {
                                break;
                            }

                            // Current track always gets added to current band.
                            currentBand.Add(track);
                            lastWidth = ulMaxWidth;
                            lastHeight = ulMaxHeight;
                        }

                        if (0 == widestBand.Count &&
                            0 == currentBand.Count)
                        {
                            // Lowest bitrate band is > maxMobileBitrate.
                            widestBand.Add(streamInfo.AvailableTracks[0]);
                        }
                        else if (currentBand.Count >= widestBand.Count)
                        {
                            // Need to check the last band which was constructed.
                            Debug.Assert(currentBand.Count > 0);
                            widestBand = currentBand; // Winner by default.
                        }

                        Debug.Assert(widestBand.Count >= 1);
                        streamInfo.RestrictTracks(widestBand);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        void video_PlaybackTrackChanged(object sender, Microsoft.Web.Media.SmoothStreaming.TrackChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            currentBitrate.Text = e.NewTrack.Bitrate.ToString();
        }

        void video_CurrentStateChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            status.Text = video.CurrentState.ToString();
        }

        private void imghdrleft_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            NavigationService.GoBack();
        }

        private void imghdrright_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Planet41VIew/Settings.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
        }
    }
```

**Refer below link also**

[Using Smooth Streaming Media Element for Windows Phone 7](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/giuseppeguerrasio/archive/2010/12/06/using-smooth-streaming-media-element-for-windows-phone-7.aspx)

[How to play videos using Smooth Streaming media element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16689005/how-to-play-videos-using-smooth-streaming-media-element)

Comment: But how does this solve the problem of accessing videos in the phone library?

Comment: @anderZubi, good question. I think that we don't have solution for get video from library. I don't understand, why...